# What is the definition of a charge-neutral operator?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, condensed-matter, terminology, cpt-symmetry

What is the definition of a [charge-neutral operator](https://www.google.com/#q=%22charge-neutral+operator%22)? I guess it means something like: it is invariant under charge conjugation. It that correct?